# How do I open the secret doors?

Tags: dmc-devil-may-cry

During playing DMC, I stumbled upon a couple of doors, which seem to be magically locked by a blue web of fibres.

[image]

[image]

I know you can open some doors with special keys, but that does not seem to apply to those blue doors. I also haven't found any explanation in the game yet.

How do you open those blue doors and what lies behind them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doors of that type may be cut apart by any Angelic weapon. The game will make it obvious once you have a weapon of that type and will instruct you to take one of these doors down using it.

Beyond that sort of door may lie any of the various collectable that the game offers, such as lost souls or keys, though they may also be placed upon the main path through the level.